# Password submission in Python

Tags: python, web-applications, password-protection, password-encryption

I am developing a website using Google app engine and I want to know what is the proper way to handle the submission.

I was thinking of doing something like hashing the password client-side with some salt, and then hash it again with some other salt on the server-side.

I want to know if this is at least some decent security, and if it already exists a Python library that does just that or something better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard practice is to use SSL encryption for the connection (e.g. https), then hash it with a salt on the server side. When later a user logs in, you will have to still verify the password and sending a hash of the password from browser to server is just as insecure as sending the password itself; an attacker that intercepts either can still log in as that user.

There is a python package called [`passlib`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/passlib) that can take care of the various forms of password hashing and salting for you:

```
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
hashed = sha256_crypt.encrypt(password)
```

It is generally a good idea to include the choosen algorithm in the stored password hash; RFC 2307 passwords (as used in LDAP) use a `{SCHEME}` prefix, other hash schemes use a unix `$digit$` prefix, where digit is a number; the `sha256` scheme in the code snippet above uses `$5$` as a prefix.

That way you can upgrade your password scheme at a later time while still supporting older schemes by choosing the correct hashing algorithm to verify a password at a later time.

Most `passlib` hashing schemes already return hashes with their standard prefix, documented in each scheme's detailed documentation page. You can use the [`.identify()` function](http://packages.python.org/passlib/password_hash_api.html#passlib.ifc.PasswordHash.identify) to identify what hash algorithm was used when you later need to verify a password hash against an entered password.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use TLS (HTTPS). It isn't perfect, but it is better than nothing (and *way* better than digest authentication).
2. If you don't want to store passwords, you can let Google take care of everything: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth
3. If you do want to worry about storing passwords, use passlib, as explained by Martijn Pieters.

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for a digest authentication. Digest Auth is secure, that means, the password is not transfered in clear text. However, the communication after the auth is not encrypted.

See a full example here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/302378-digest-authentication/

Comment: Digest Auth headers are never used these days.

Comment: Moreover, using Digest these days is a *very bad* idea indeed, since it uses MD5 hashes only. They are no longer considered secure.

Comment: However - I wanted to point the question opener to a way of implementing it. The way Digest mitigates replay-attacks should be used in every non-SSL-Auth.